# How to run erlang from c application?

Tags: erlang

is it possible to run erlang vm from withing C application? I'd like to use as script engine from my game and cannot find any erlang API or other "official" way how to do that ...

Thanks!

Comment: I answered the question, but personally I think, that there are better options for scripting (e.g. Lua). It is possible to do with Erlang, but it is just much more work.

Answer (score 2):

Erlang VM takes some time to boot, so it wouldn't make sense to start and stop it each time, you want to make a call. The only solution is to have it running all the time (it is not that heavy). You can communicate with your C code using raw TCP or C nodes. You can read more about different interoperability options here:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/users_guide.html

Erlang is good for orchestration, while C++ is good for raw computation, so usually people do it the other way round: they call C from Erlang.